# How to write $|\sin x|$ as a piecewise function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I can't work out how to write $f(x) = |\sin x|$ as a piecewise function.

$$
     f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \sin x,? \leq x< ? \\
 -\sin x, ?\leq x< ?
\end{cases}
$$
What should the $x$'s be between?

Comment: Hint: take a look at the graph and, in particular, try to find the points where $\sin{x}$ changes its sign between $+$ and $-$.

Comment: $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \sin x &  \text{ if } 2n\pi \leq x\leq (2n+1)\pi\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb Z , \\
 -\sin x&\text{ if }(2m+1)\pi \leq x\leq 2(m+1)\pi\text{ for some }m\in\Bbb Z .
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Approach very similar to Matti P.'s comment: Consider the unit circle [i.e. radius = 1] centered at (0,0).  Let $\theta$ represent any particular point on this circle, which means that $\theta$ represents the arc length of a particular point on the circle. Here, 1 complete revolution around circle has an arc length of $2\pi$.  $\sin \theta$ represents the $y$ coordinate for a particular value of $\theta$.  When $\theta$ is in the upper half plane, $\sin \theta > 0$, with the reverse for $\theta$ in the lower half plane.  Consider this visualization against the backdrop of O-th User's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by definition you have $$|\sin(x)|:=\left\{\begin{aligned} \sin(x), \sin(x)\geq 0 \\ -\sin(x), \quad \sin(x)<0\end{aligned} \right. = \left\{\begin{aligned} \sin(x), \quad  2\pi n \leq x \leq 2\pi n+\pi \\ -\sin(x), \quad 2\pi n-\pi<x<2\pi n\end{aligned} \right., \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, you are allowed to write

$$
     f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \sin x,&\sin x\ge0 \\
 -\sin x,&\sin x\le 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: This made me laugh lol

Answer (score 0):

You have that $( k \in \Bbb {Z} )$:

For $  \pi \ge x \ge 0  \pmod {2k \pi}$

You have: $$\sin x \ge 0 \implies |\sin x|=\sin x$$
And:
For $  \pi \le x \le 2\pi \pmod {2k \pi }$

You have $$\sin x \le 0 \implies |\sin x|=-\sin x$$